# C++ Programming Error | Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

So I'm trying to make a simple program and I keep getting an **'undeclared identifier error'** with my name, author, price, isbn, quantity, first result, and second result, in the console. I apologize if this type of this has already been asked but I have not been able to fix it.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string name, author,
        double isbn,
        float price,
        int quantity,
        float firstresult,
        float secondresult,
        const float tax (0.07);

    cout << "What is the name of the book?";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "What is the authors name?";
    cin >> author;
    cout << "What is the ISBN number?";
    cin >> isbn;
    cout << "What is the price?";
    cin >> price;
    cout << "How many books did you purchase?";
    cin >> quantity;

    firstresult = price*tax;
    secondresult = price + firstresult;

    if (quantity > 5) {
        secondresult += (quantity - 5) * 2.00;
    }

    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Invoice of Order:" << endl;
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << author << endl;
    cout << isbn << endl;
    cout << price << endl;
    cout << quantity << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost: " << secondresult << endl;
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can't define variables of differen types in the same line.  You need semicolons, not commas at the end of each line at the top of your main where you declare all those variables.  The error messages from clang are quite clear what the problem is: https://godbolt.org/g/CTefhu

Comment: for `std::string` inputs you should use `std::getline(std::cin, stringVariable);` and you should define `string` variables to empty string `variable = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to declare multiple local variables of different types by separating them with comma `,` which is wrong. Use separate statements to declare your variables and apply semicolon `;` instead. Semicolon marks the end of an statement:

```
string name, author; // you are defining multiple variables of the same type which is fine
double isbn;
float price;
int quantity;
float firstresult;
float secondresult;
const float tax (0.07);
```

Those are not function parameters in which case they would be separated by comma. That being said you should use the [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) when accepting strings from the standard input:

```
std::getline(std::cin, author);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron, I really appreciate it!